# Capturing ui:TabSetEvent?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a lightning component that is embedded on a lightning page tab. My goal is to refresh the component when someone clicks on the same tab after its loaded. I tried handling the application level notifications but the tabs only emit component events.

```
     <aura:handler event="aura:applicationEvent" action="{!c.eventListener}" />
```

so my question is whether I can handle the tabSet event generated by the standard lightning page or if I'm SOL.

testing a handler produces a runtime error:

```
  <aura:handler name="tabset" event="ui:tabsetEvent" action="{!c.eventListener}" />
```

> Deployment Failed: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION - An unexpected error occurred.
>   Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 2040237501-32662
>   (518856820)

Comment: Where did you find 'event="ui:tabsetEvent' handler details? Share some documentation, its quite new and I have never seen it.

Comment: I pulled it off of the event log when I click on a tab. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/inspector_events.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lightning platform currently has a few `access` modifiers on each of the components which indicate if they are designed to be listened to by developers, rather than internal salesforce components.

The one you have found through the event log cannot be accessed as it is marked `PRIVILEGED`.

In the github repo, the [ui:tabSetEvent](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura-components/src/main/components/ui/tabsetEvent/tabsetEvent.evt) is marked as such.

In comparison, here is a GA event, [ui:menuSelect](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura-components/src/main/components/ui/menuSelect/menuSelect.evt)

So, for now, we can only listen to the documented (aka GA-ed) events in the [component library here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/events)